# Jupyter Server Reachable from outside but refuse localhost connection

Tags: server, localhost, jupyter-notebook, hosting, web-hosting

I've Setup a Jupyter Notebook Server on computer A with the following configuration:

```
c.NotebookApp.certfile = '.jupyter/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.ip = 'MY_IP_ADDRESS'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = '.jupyter/mykey.key'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'Dropbox/GitHub'
c.NotebookApp.password = 'MY_HASHED_PASSWORD'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

When the server starts, computer B can reach to this server with `https://MY_IP_ADDRESS:8888`.

But Computer A couldn't reach to itself in any kind

```
# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://localhost:8888/
https://127.0.0.1:8888/

# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
https://MY_IP_ADDRESS:8888/
```

Worth mentioned is that when I comment out the line which assign the IP address, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` works fine, but I wouldn't be able to connect from outside (computer B)

I've tried switching port, switching browsers, configure `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` and some other options inside `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

but none of them seems to work
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

## Update 1

After some further investigation, it turns out this has nothing to do with jupyter notebook. I ran a simple python HTTP server with the following snippet:

```
import sys
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import http.server


def test(HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,
         ServerClass=http.server.HTTPServer):

    protocol = "HTTP/1.0"
    host = 'MY_IP_ADDRESS'
    port = 8888
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        arg = sys.argv[1]
        if ':' in arg:
            host, port = arg.split(':')
            port = int(port)
        else:
            try:
                port = int(sys.argv[1])
            except:
                host = sys.argv[1]

    server_address = (host, port)

    HandlerClass.protocol_version = protocol
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print("Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "...")
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The results are the same. I'm guessing this is actually a normal behavior, but just not my favor:(

So that leads into two circumstances:

- for self-connecting

  - binding IP address: "" (empty string)
  - use localhost or 127.0.0.1
  - (but other client won't be able to connect)
- for other client connecting

  - binging IP address: "MY_IP_ADDRESS"
  - use MY_IP_ADDRESS:8888
  - (but server itself won't be able to connect)

I've added some new tag, hope anyone will have hint on this><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be answering my own ancient question.

In order to bind service on every address, use the [0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) special address.